# save changes before exit on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var save;

$('textarea').on('input', function(){
    save = 1;
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    if(save == 1){// ajax code to save changes;}
});
```

So if I type something inside a textarea and close the browser's tab - the changes are saved if I'm on localhost (xamp, chrome).

The same code on remote server doesn't work - changes are not saved.

Any help?

Comment: depending on the data, look at using `navigator.sendBeacon` - the *only reliable* option (without too much bother)

Comment: @Bravo, `depending on data` - could you a bit explain, pls. My data is a textarea content, i.e. text of various size. Is there any limit, or... what?

Comment: depends on what and how much you want to send

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `beforeunload` quits the browser simultaneously while executing code, so it depends on the timing of server (or it has something on it).

The painful answer is by using `preventDefault` inside of that function before ajax:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(save == 1){// ajax code to save changes;}
});
```

Comment: Simply - doesn't work. Tab is closed and data not saved.

Comment: is it differ from other browser as well?